# Normalizing Foreign Keys with Junction & Lookup Tables

Tags: database, foreign-keys, normalization, lookup, junction

I've been scratching my head lately over the relationship between database normalization and foreign keys with respect to junction tables and lookup tables.

I’ve currently have the following tables: Users, UserTypes, Roles, UsersInRoles, and Permissions. UserTypes is simply a lookup table providing the name of the type, with description, via a foreign key in the Users table. Roles are the various roles with associated Permissions linked to each User via the UsersInRoles table.

**I need to come up with a structure that allows me to** provide multiple Roles for each User, in addition to special permissions for each respective User that may not be covered in the fixed Roles of which they are a member.

I had a foreign key to my UsersInRoles table from the Users table, but decided that it just didn’t make sense. Conversely, it seems to make perfect sense to use a foreign key from the Users table to the UserTypes table. Is this the rule of thumb? That junction tables have foreign keys linking to the primary keys of the tables it joins, while master tables have foreign keys linking to the primary key of associated lookup tables?

**Parameters:**

- Each User can have one or multiple Roles
- Each Role has a fixed set of Permissions
- Each User can have additional Permissions not provided by their Roles

I suspect I may also need a PermissionsInRoles junction table as well as one for PermissionsInUsers? But this is just ridiculous isn't it? There just must be a better way. I'm thoroughly convinced that I'm losing my mind here, lol. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This has got my head spinning :P

**UPDATE**
Is this basically how it would be setup? I might get rid of the UsersInRoles table so each user can only be in one role, and additional permissions can be added via the SpecialPermissions junction table. From a UI standpoint, I was thinking it might be good when assigning permissions to a user, selecting a "Role" would simply check the appropriate boxes associated with that role, then you customize that and submit. That way I think I would only need a junction table between the Users and Permissions tables perhaps? Ugh. This is quite daunting for a first time database designer haha. Remember when you were just starting out? Or maybe you guys are more of a genius than I am, lol.

[Schema Image link](http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/4752/basicsecurityschema.png) (can't post images yet)

Here's a neat scholarly article (albeit 10 years old) on query-driven database design titled: "[Robust Database Design for Diverse Query Patterns](http://www.misrc.umn.edu/workingpapers/fullPapers/2001/0119_090101.pdf)". The Conclusion section has an interesting approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your securables are just a products table (or set of tables), and you're using SSMS (SQL-Server Management Studio) then you should not be inventing your own security schema from scratch.

What I would recommend is that you setup your users and roles in SSMS -- expand the Database, then --> Security --> Users, etc.  Right-click a user, look for securables, and then you can assign the user to roles, or also, just objects (tables, etc.) directly.  Or right-click roles and you have similar options.  Whatever you do, stay away from creating your own security schema, if you can help it.

If you need your web app to have access to the database, then look into "utility accounts" (these are like users, created at the server level instead of the database level, but then you can bring them into your database from there.); or look into impersonation if you're able to pass users' creds from your internal network when they login to the database.  Utility accounts or users can be assigned to roles, or granted direct access to database objects without roles -- whatever you need.

Comment: Well this built-in security is for Database users correct? What I'm trying to accomplish is a series of tables for storing users and their permissions for interacting with the database **VIA a website portal**. This will all be implemented on an internal web-app. I'm trying to keep this a simple, yet extensible as possible. I'm just an intern mind you. I haven't got the years of DB experience yet unfortunately.

Comment: I hear you -- you're a professional, but you're just an intern, and you're not a student.  You've got some good advice here -- you can use the built-in security -- which WILL work for your situation; or alternatively, you can use the custom model I described in my first answer, which WILL ALSO work for your situation.  You're mixing mu notions of 'normalization' with notions of data-types and indexing...and so far, you've disqualified at least 2 good answers based on, I think, your own mis-understanding.  I recommend you give one or both of these ideas a shot, and see how they work for you.

Comment: Noted. Thank you for your input. I will give it some thought and try to get something functional out of it. ["professional" in that I'm getting paid, but yes, an intern. It's a learning process.]

Answer (score 1):

> I suspect I may also need a PermissionsInRoles junction table as well
>   as one for PermissionsInUsers?

Well, you already said one of the requirements was "Each Role has a fixed set of Permissions". So to fulfill that requirement, you need to store permissions that apply to each role.

```
Table: role_permissions
PK:    (Role, Permission)

Role    Permission
--
User    Create
User    Update
Admin   Create
Admin   Update
Admin   Delete
```

You don't need *two* different tables to implement that requirement.

By the same token, you've already said "Each User can have additional Permissions not provided by their Roles". To fulfill that requirement, you have to store user-specific permissions.

```
Table: user_permissions
PK:    (username, permission)

username    permission
--
user1       Rename
user1       Leak to News of the World
user2       Randomly corrupt data
```

So, again, you don't need *two* different tables to implement that requirement. Both those tables are in 5NF.

> But this is just ridiculous isn't it?

What's ridiculous?

- That you have very elaborate requirements for permissions?
- That you store business data (like permissions) in tables?
- That it takes more than one table to model your permission requirements?
- Something else?

If you want specific advice about your actual tables, edit your question and insert DDL for your tables.

---

**Later**

I looked at your diagram. Not every table needs an id number; id numbers have nothing to do with normalization.

If I were designing your system, I probably wouldn't use id numbers in the tables Roles, Permissions, and UserTypes until I saw a performance problem that id numbers could fix. (In most systems over the last 30 years, that means, well, almost never.) Before I used an id number, I'd also consider and test using a human-readable code instead. Human-readable codes often don't require joins; id numbers always require joins.

In most SQL dbms, you can combine a data type and check constraint in a `CREATE DOMAIN` statement. In PostgreSQL, you might use something like this to reduce the number of tables.

```
CREATE DOMAIN role AS VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL
  CHECK (VALUE in ('Admin', 'User', 'Guest'));
```

Followed by

```
CREATE TABLE user_roles (
  user_id integer not null references users (id),
  role_name role 
);
```

Replacing a table with a `CREATE DOMAIN` statement is most useful when the number of rows is stable and relatively small. Personally, I'd rather have the tables.

If you stick with id numbers, you also need UNIQUE constraints on Roles.RoleName, Permissions.Description, and UserTypes.UserType.

Otherwise, you seem to be doing fine.

Comment: I posted a link to an image of the generic schema that I threw together in Access real fast (I'm developing in SQL Server 2008 R2 though, just to reiterate that). As for your suggestions, so you're saying that I only need two tables in place of four? Let me modify that schema to take into account what I think you're saying.

Comment: Actually, I don't like the having multiple records for each user-permission relationship idea. Seems messy to me, and, isn't this non-normal? Please forgive my ignorance, college really doesn't do squat to prepare you for real development. I did my best to get any experience I could, but it seems it still wasn't enough. Ugh.

Comment: Btw, I was taught that whenever text is repeated in a table (such as the username in your example) that it should be replaced with an int foreign key and reference a lookup table. Would you say this is a good idea? It would only be a simply "join" to bring them back together in a query.

Comment: No, as a general rule it's not a good idea. Normalization has nothing to do with replacing a text column with a number column that references another table.

Comment: @Chiramisu: No, I don't think it's a good idea in the general case. You have to test. I worked on one system that had queries with 20+ joins. All of the joins were required, because they'd replaced text with id numbers "to improve performance". (They had other problems, too, because they'd omitted several necessary UNIQUE constraints.) I got rid of all but two of the id numbers; overall select performance improved by more than 30 to 1. Queries that once took 10 minutes took 20 seconds; some queries that took 4 or 5 seconds returned in 40 milliseconds.

Comment: @Catcall: You've been a tremendous help and I thank you sir. You said "If I were designing your system, I probably wouldn't use id numbers in the tables Roles, Permissions, and UserTypes until I saw a performance problem that id numbers could fix." I can see for UserTypes, but the other two would create redundant date which can cause an "update anomaly" from what I understand. Anyway, I think I've bothered everyone enough. I greatly appreciate all the sage advice :)

Comment: @Catcall: Both of you were very helpful. Out of courtesy I gave the rep to user542398 since he has less. I would vote your answer up, but I can't yet because I don't have any rep. I will when I have enough, cheers :)

Comment: @Chiramisu, you're a good sport.  I'll be honest with you -- college takes you just so far -- and I have yet to hire someone fresh out of school who was good at databases.  You obviously have a head for it, in any case, as you're asking good questions, so it's just a matter of time now.  If you ever have the time, I'd recommend going through some of the tutorials on www.asp.net that involve adventureworks, or also the MCTS (test prep) books are also good for getting you up and going on new topics.  I use those each time a new version comes out just to get up to speed.

Comment: @kuru kuru na...: ^.^ arigatou. I like the name, you speak Japanese? Anyway, I'll check into that. I LOVE Information Systems. I really do, so yeah I have a strong passion for learning this stuff. I've taken your previous advice and am reading anything I can find about Schemas, Roles, and Users. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Chiramisu: You're mistaken about update anomalies. If you throw away the id numbers, all three of those tables have a single column, and that single column is the primary key. That means all three of those tables are in 5NF. You don't often find better protection against update anomalies than that. (As long as other tables have foreign keys set correctly.)

Answer (score 0):

One thing I've done before, in a similar-sounding scenario:

Keep Roles and users in the same table.

Have an objects table (the tables/queries/forms/etc. you will be granting permissions to)

Have a permission table -- this is where you will link roles/users to objects (i.e., John can SELECT on table 1)

Finally, have an Inheritance table -- this is where you will link roles/users to each other (i.e., John has permission to do whatever Role1 can do)

For example -- a structure like this:

For example:

```
Users Table:
UserID -- User -- UserTypeID
1 ------- John Smith --- 1
2 ------- Sally Fort --- 1
3 ------- Public Role -- 2
4 ------- Special Role - 2

UserType Table:
UserTypeID -- Description
1 ----------- Human Being
2 ----------- Role

Objects Table:
1 -- Data-Entry Form 1
2 -- Data-Entry Form 2
3 -- Query 1
4 -- Table 1

Permissions Table
UserID -- ObjectID -- Permission
1      -- 1        -- Update (This says John can Update Data-Entry Form 1 (via direct permission))
3      -- 1        -- Update (This says that the Public Role can Update Data-Entry Form 1)
3      -- 2        -- Update (...as well as Data-Entry Form 2)
4      -- 3        -- Select (This says that the special role can Select from Query1)
4      -- 4        -- Insert (...the special role can Insert into Table1)

Permission Inheritance Table
UserID -- UserID_ToInheritFrom
1      -- 3 (this says John can do whatever the Public Role can do)
1      -- 4 (this says John can do whatever the Special Role can do)
2      -- 3 (this says Sally can do whatever the Public Role can do)
```

So then if you wanted to query, "What can John do?", you'd do something like this:

```
SELECT
   ObjectID,
   Permission
FROM
   PermissionsTable
WHERE
   UserID = 1 -- John has direct permission
   OR UserID IN (SELECT UserID_ToInheritFrom FROM PermissionInheritanceTable WHERE UserID = 1)
   -- John has indirect permission via the Permission Inheritance Table (or you can call it the "role
   -- membership table" if that's easier for you to think of that way.)
```

This implementation works well.  If you want to see a similar implementation, look at SQL-Server's implementation (or better yet, USE it, instead of re-creating the wheel from scratch.)

Comment: Your Users table doesn't make any sense though >.< Users and Roles are going to have completely different Fields :(
Same goes for your Objects table pretty much.
An interesting thought, but I think this strays way too far from a normalized database. I appreciate the effort, but I'm looking for a different approach. Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe you don't know quite what 'normalized' means...  Or it's just not making sense to you that users and roles are essentially the same thing.  Anyway, this is a pretty 'normal' implementation.  Is this a class assignment or something?  One thing you might consider doing is taking a look at an existing security schema -- As I said, SQL-server has one that does everything you're asking -- I know Oracle does too, and who knows what else.

Comment: I edited it a little -- added a user-type table (lookup table), and a few minor things.  But as @Catcall says, if this is too far off from what you had in mind, then put some code-up so we can see what you're trying to do / how you envision it being done (sounds like you already know what you want it to look like) / or where you're getting stuck.

Comment: I'm familiar with the normalization concept, yes. No, I'm no longer a student, I am a professional developer, albeit not a veteran yet but I'm no dummy :P
I am currently using SQL Server 2008 R2. I may post some code in a bit.

Comment: Normalization confuses a lot of folks, even the smart ones sometimes.  One thing that would help is if you could characterize the objects you're trying to control permissions for.  Are they just database objects in your SQL-Server Database, or is it for other stuff, like parts of an application you've developed, etc.

Comment: Ok sure... I'm still looking at how to go about storing them (I might use a fulltext catalog), but it will be a rather large (several thousand) catalog of products that our company produces. The web app is for internal use only and is intended to facilitate collaboration between departments on the development of various technical documentation for these products.